# Switch Play! Framework version

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, playframework

I'm working with two different projects that require different Play! Versions. I am currently using one version with one project and I need to switch it to use another version with another project. I am using Windows 7 and Eclipse. Is there an easy way to do this? I have play 1.2.4, 1.2.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Name your play bat files by their versions.

play-1.2.4.bat

play-1.2.5.bat

2) right click on computer -> properties (or just click the windows key and pause/break at once)

3) Go to Advanced System Settings

4) Go to Environment Settings

5) Go to Path->Edit In the little box that comes up with all the directories, add your own directory for where you are keeping your play folders.

ex: D:\play-1.2.4;D:\play-1.2.5

6) you can now use the different versions in CMD prompt

ex: play-1.2.4 start filename